Is there a way to express a "function of any kind" in Haskell's type signature?
My newbie's attempt to express the behavior of operator || from C/C++ in Haskell:
orElse :: Bool -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
orElse True _ = const True
orElse False pred = pred

Can this be generalized so that it can accept a -> b -> Bool, a -> b -> c -> Bool and so on as its 2nd argument?
Looked at overloading techniques, HKTs et. al. - nothing seems to deal with generalization by kind...
Edit: I now understand why this was a bad example (reading the definition of operator|| in prelude helped) but am still wondering at the larger question as posed.

How is that related to operator ||? I'd expect orElse :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool --- why the additional argument a, and why only on the second argument?

The analogy with operator|| is sequencing: if left side is True then right side is not evaluated no matter its strictness requirements. Maybe I'm off base here completely... the intended use was something like:
anyOf :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
anyOf pred = foldl' (flip orElse pred) False
elem' :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => a -> f a -> Bool
elem' y = anyOf (== y)

Haskell's || is already lazy in its second argument...

Ok, so this particular case is moot - thank you! The larger question stands, is it possible to operate on functions of different kinds generically? Or is this simply something that is never required for various reasons such the one above?

I was picturing using a type family to recursively recognize functions that ultimately return Bool, but I'm not sure how (or if) you would write that.

You can probably craft your wanted function using type classes, but I'm not sure this is a great idea.
class MagicOr a where
  magicOr :: a -> a -> a 

instance MagicOr Bool where
  magicOr = (||)

instance MagicOr b => MagicOr (a -> b) where
  magicOr f g = \x -> f x `magicOr` g x
  -- or, alternatively,
  -- magicOr = liftA2 magicOr

The code above defines a magicOr function that can be used on two arguments of type Bool, or of type a -> Bool, or of type a -> b -> Bool, and so on.
So far, I guess this code is not too bad, and fairly usable.
Still, depending on what you actually need to do, you might end up building a complex type class machinery, which might be somewhat fragile to use. An example is printf. Its definition is rather tricky since it has to handle an unknown number of parameters. Further, if used wrong, it can confuse the type checker which will spew error messages which are hard to understand.
Feel free to experiment, of course, and see by yourself. Just be warned that type classes, when abused too much, sometimes lead to unwieldy code.

Thank you! I think I understand the typeclass pattern here...

Note the similarity with the Semigroup instances for Any and for functions. The only difference here is that you avoid a newtype.

@NaïmFavier Good point. When using a -> b -> ... -> Any my magicOr is just (<>). And Any is just Bool with another name (so that the or-semigroup operation is used).
